# Printed Circuit Board manufacturing file for Radio Jove?

Tags: amateur-observing, radio-astronomy, jupiter

I woild like to build a **Radio Jove receiver** whose [design is available on NASA website](https://radiojove.gsfc.nasa.gov/telescope/). However, I don't want to purchase the receiver, I would like to make it, but but I don't have any knowledge about the [PCB design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board). **May
someone please help me to get the PCB manufacturing file?**

Comment: the [manual](https://radiojove.gsfc.nasa.gov/telescope/rcvr_manual.pdf) has a circuit diagram. If you need help with creating a pcb file. If you want advice with pcb manufacture, you may be better off asking at electronics

Comment: But go slow, Electronics SE is not as nice as Astronomy SE. So a simple question like "how can I make a PCB?" might get closed very quickly and down-voted.

Comment: The "X-ray view" in Figure 4 gives some indication of the traces. You could try redrawing that in some program. Or you could just get some perforated board (remember that?) and to a bunch of soldering. There's a good chance though that it wouldn't work; it's easy to overheat the transistors unless you use sockets.

Comment: @uhoh I summarized the comments into an accessible answer to simplify life of the readers. Comments and suggestions for improvements are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As [@JamesK](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/2365/james-k) already mentioned in a comment, the [RCV manual](https://radiojove.gsfc.nasa.gov/telescope/rcvr_manual.pdf) contains a circuit diagram on page 14:

[image: Circuit diagram]

From your question it is not clear to me how much experience you have with PCB design and which software you are using. Back in the days, I had contact with [Autodesk's EAGLE](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/), but there are [other free PCB alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/eaglecad/?license=free) like [librepcb](https://librepcb.org/). In worst case, you do in fact have to redraw your design.

For prototyping, so-called [breadboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadboard) do a pretty good job, which was mentioned in the comments as well by [@uhoh](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/7982/uhoh).

#### References

- On electronics.SE: [Is there a directory of open source hardware projects?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5424/is-there-a-directory-of-open-source-hardware-projects)

Comment: *Beautiful!* Thanks for putting everything together in an answer post.